# Popup window when checkbox has not been checked

Tags: javascript

Is this jQuery, or JavaScript? My assignment disallows the use of jQuery.

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var collection = document.getElementsByName('deliveryType'),
        cds = document.getElementsByName('cd[]'),
        cdTotal = 0,
        L = collection.length;

    while(L--) {
        if(collection[L].checked) {   // get shipping costs
            collection = Number(collection[L].getAttribute('title')); 
            break;
        }
    }

    L = cds.length;
    while(L--) {
        if(cds[L].checked) {    //add total prices
            cdTotal += Number(cds[L].getAttribute('title'));
        }
    }

    //  output total
    document.getElementById('total').value = collection + cdTotal;
}
```

Comment: This is *pure* JavaScript. Is that all your question?

Comment: Your code is lacking something...you have too many closing `}` statements.

Comment: are you asking how to do a popup?  If so it's just alert('message');

Comment: What is your question exactly? Like you want to know if the above code is the JavaScript style or jQuery Style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pure javascript - if you're not sure just look for the inclusion of jQuery somewhere.  It usually looks like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>`

you could also check what resources are loaded by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser.

Comment: Does it matter with the `src` name?

Comment: @Ali - I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Thank you guys, major help!!

Comment: @m.edmondson I'm just not sure about this part `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>` so I'm wondering where exactly this is different than JavaScript? I'm new to jQuery too

Comment: @RobiHaque you should accept this answer if it is answered your question :)

Comment: @Ali The jquery.js would be a reference to a local file which would contain the JQuery library. You can also reference externally: __<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js">__. The 'src' attribute indicates the location of the script file.

Comment: @user1506980 I totally understand that part, but what I was wondering is that wouldn't JavaScript also using the same way? except the content of the file would be different?

Comment: I think you're confused by the fact that jQuery is a library built on top of javascript.  Hence javascript wouldn't need the above `<script>` tag but jQuery does.

Answer (score 2):

Just JavaScript. You'll see a dollar sign '$' or the 'JQuery' keyword if you're using JQuery. Read up more on the API Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/